# what value of $\eta$ makes this a valid pdf

Tags: probability, integration

The pdf is $f(t) = \eta  e^{-\frac{t}{30}}$, for $t>0$

I understand that in order to make the valid pdf, the $f(t)$ needs to equal $0$. But I get a bit confused with the answer. Can someone please check it whether I did it correctly?

[image]

Comment: the f(t) equal to 1. sorry that was a typo

Comment: You can click the "edit" button on the bottom left of your question post to remedy any typos.

Comment: You did not integrate correctly. Check again.

Comment: Unfortunately, there appear to be several typos.  are given that $f(t)= Ye^{t/30}$ but are you saying that "f(1)= 1" or "F(t)= 1", where "f(t)" is the probability density" and "F" is the "cumulative probability function.  It appears to be the latter.  $F(1)= \int_0^1 Ye^{-t/30} dt=$$ -\frac{Y}{30}\left(e^{-1/30}- e^0\right)=-\frac{Y}{30}\left(e^{-1/30}-1\right)= Y\frac{1-1/30}{30}= 1$ so $Y= \frac{30}{1- \frac{1}{30}}$

Answer (score 1):

You wrote $\left[\frac{e^{-t/30}}{-1/30}\right]^\infty_0$ but then, for some reason, you calculated $\left[\frac{e^{-t/30}}{-1/30}\right]^\infty_1$ instead. Otherwise it's ok.